# Is there any way to go back to the line you just edited in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Let's say, if I am reading code in one xxx.cs file. Now I am in Line 100, but I find a method in this line, and Press F12 go to the definithion of the method in 300. When I finished reading the definition, I wanna go back to Line 100. Now I have to scroll up the screen and search for the Line 100. Is there any easy way for this, such as making a bookmark? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the commands "View.NavigateBackward" and "View.NavigateForward", that do exactly what you need. By default, they are bound to Ctrl+- and Ctrl+Shift+- respectively (use the minus in the main part of the keyboard, not on the numpad):

[image: View.Navigate commands]

Answer (score 0):

Control Hyphen! Best shortcut ever.